# Video Editing, Is there a way to make the speed value animated?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes, drivers, graph-editor

I added a **Speed Control** filter onto a clip inside the **Video Sequence Editor**. When I tried to make the **Multiply Speed** value of this filter animated, both by making it a key frame and by making it dependent from a driver, I got the error message: *Multiply Speed cannot be animated.*

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Why is this value not able to be animated?
- Is there a way, for instance an add-on to make it work?

My goal is to  make a movie play at first very fast but then drop the speed continously until it is played in slow motion.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience it is much easier to use speed control disabling *Use as speed*.

[image]

You can then just re-map frames using graph editor (after you've pressed <kbd>I</kbd> over the *Frame number*).
Allows for smooth speed transitions or sharp ones, whatever you like.

This makes it also much easier to pick the exact frame from which the speed will be changing.

Comment: thank you,  Sorry, I did not understand what you explained, for instance "press I for keyframe over the Frame number" ...I don*t get it where to click for the value "frame number" ...inside the filter or somewhere else?

Comment: I've added picture. If you go to properties of strip. Select speed effect strip, (open properties panel if not open yet), find "Effect Strip" section and deselect `Use as speed`. Then you should get `Frame number` which you can animate as any other normal property.